# Securing Wordpress in Azure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, azure, iis

I'm likely going to be moving a bunch of Wordpress sites to Azure in the coming months. I'm currently on an Apache VPS.

I made sure to take the time to lock down my sites via .htaccess as much as I could. How would I translate this into a web.config file? See below:

```
# Protects .htaccess
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</files>

# Protects config file
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Block WordPress xmlrpc.php requests
<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```